# Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge

Tags: sms

How do I stop my text messages from coming through my emails?  Text messages are coming through my work email computer.  I am trying to unsuccessfully find the turn off for the sms.  However, I cannot find it or directions.  I have found directions for the S4, but those are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Native Email application

Select 'More'

Select Settings

Select your work/email account

Scroll down to 'Exchange ActiveSync Settings'

Turn 'Sync Messages' to OFF